# Why is the metaclass not being used in this case?

Tags: python, metaclass

My question is two-fold: First, I don't understand why the`__new__()` method of the`MetaBoundedInt` metaclass is not being called by the definition of the class`BoundedInt`and secondly would like to know how to get it work. At this point, I don't know if it works properly since it's not even being executed -- so my question is not really about that at this point (but if you spot something, or have a comment or suggestion in that regard, feel free to to bring it up. ;-).

I suspect the problem has something to do with fact that`BoundedInt`is a subclass of the built-in`int`rather than`object`, but was unable to find anything in the documentation indicating that subclassing a built-in had to be handled differently somehow.

**Update:** Sorry I didn't realize I was running the script with Python 3.3.4. In Python 2.7.6 the `MetaBoundInt.__new__()`method is indeed being called -- so now I'm wondering why there's a difference. Meanwhile I'll get back to trying to make it work (this is a repackaging -- nesting -- into a metaclass, of some code I had working in both Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.3.4).

```
import functools

class MetaBoundedInt(type):
    # int arithmetic methods that return an int
    _specials = ('abs add and div floordiv invert lshift mod mul neg or pos '
                 'pow radd rand rdiv rfloordiv rlshift rmod rmul ror rpow '
                 'rrshift rshift rsub rtruediv rxor sub truediv xor').split()
    _ops = set('__%s__' % name for name in _specials)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print('in MetaBoundedInt.__new__()')
        classobj = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        # create wrappers for all inherited int arithmetic ops
        for name, meth in ((n, m) for n, m in vars(int).items() if n in cls._ops):
            setattr(classobj, name, cls._DecoratedIntMethod(cls, meth))
        return classobj

    class _DecoratedIntMethod(object):
        def __init__(self, cls, func):
            self.cls, self.func = cls, func

        def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
            # assume obj is a BoundedInt instance
            @functools.wraps(self.func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                # return result of calling self.func() as BoundedInt
                return self.cls(self.func(obj, *args, **kwargs),
                                bounds=obj._bounds)
            return wrapper

class BoundedInt(int):
    __metaclass__ = MetaBoundedInt
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        lower, upper = bounds = kwargs.pop('bounds')
        val = int.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)  # support multiple int() args
        if val < lower:
            val = int.__new__(cls, lower)
        elif val > upper:
            val = int.__new__(cls, upper)
        val._bounds = bounds
        return val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = BoundedInt('64', 16, bounds=(0, 100))  # 0x64 == 100
    print('type(v)={}, value={}'.format(type(v).__name__, v))
    v += 10
    print('type(v)={}, value={}'.format(type(v).__name__, v))
    w = v + 10
    print('type(v)={}, value={}'.format(type(w).__name__, w))
    x = v - 110
    print('type(v)={}, value={}'.format(type(x).__name__, x))
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 2.7.6. Are you sure it's not calling `__new__`?

Comment: MetaBoundedInt is metaclass of BoundedInt, so why we define __new__ in BoundedInt.

Comment: You can overload them.  It's a very complicated way of doing this though?

Comment: when you defined this staement `__metaclass__ = MetaBoundedInt` python will call the constructor `__new__` from that class.

Comment: It's calling new on the meta class then new on the class when you create a BoundedInt.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog: Yes, the `__new__()` of the metaclass should be called when the `BoundedInt` class is defined. The  `__new__()` in `BoundedInt` will only called when instances of it are created. The former not happening is the problem, but it only happens in Py 3.3.4. Until I figure out why, I'll have to use v2.7.6 to work on the other remaining unrelated issues with what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I didn't realize I was running the script with Python 3.3.4. In Python 2.7.6 the `MataBoundInt.__new__()`method is indeed being called -- so now I'm wondering why there's a difference.

The difference is because in Python 3, you specify a metaclass through the `metaclass` keyword argument to the `class` statement:

```
class BoundedInt(int, metaclass=MetaBoundedInt):
```

This was changed so that the metaclass could get involved earlier in the class creation process, changing how variable and function definitions operate within the class statement instead of merely postprocessing the class's dict. See [PEP 3115](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) for details.

Comment: Of course (pounds head with fist) -- should have remembered to use the trick from the `six` library to write metaclass declarations that work in both version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BoundedInt must be a subclass of object?  Just let me check up on that

It calls the metaclass new for me (python2.7) using your code as is. What you said about objects rings a bell for me though.

```
snowy:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
snowy:~$ python x.py 
in MetaBoundedInt.__new__()          <==== see
type(v)=BoundedInt, value=100
Traceback (most recent call last):    <==== and this is a separate problem.
  File "x.py", line 53, in <module>
    v += 10
  File "x.py", line 24, in __get__
    @functools.wraps(self.func)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'wrapper_descriptor' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

try running isinstance(int, object) it returns true for me.

> ```
> Note
> Historically (until release 2.2), Python’s built-in types have differed from
> user-defined types because it was not possible to use the built-in types as
> the basis for object-oriented inheritance. This limitation no longer exists.
> ```

from http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html 
So I think you may have problems with old versions of Python.. (2.2 is very old though.. you'd be unlucky to see it these days I reckon).